# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. | System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, asp.net-web-api, virtual-machine

My webApi is using a third party web api Service inside it. The thing is it's perfectly working in my local machine and Azure web Service. but when I transfer this solution in to Azure Vm instance it's getting this error. I have installed correct certificates related to that 3rd party web api and registered with HttpClient and tried with

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

But it's giving the same error. I don't know what is the exact error. Could any one help on this please?

Comment: What third-party Web API are you using? Could you provide some key code about calling the third-party Web API for us to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Per my understanding, you could refer to the following approach to check this issue:

1.Leverage https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check the supported Protocols both on your side and third-party Web API as follows:

[image]

2.Configure `SecurityProtocol` and `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` as follows:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Also, you could refer to this similar [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392925/only-on-azure-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel) and [issue2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca6372be-3169-4fb5-870f-bfbea605faf6/azure-webapp-webjob-exception-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for more details.